# Is marketing a field of economics?

Tags: microeconomics, definition, marketing

I would argue that the marketing (or de-marketing as in the example of a [recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_recall#:%7E:text=A%20product%20recall%20is%20a,at%20risk%20of%20legal%20action.)) of goods and services is an implementation of knowledge and experience in microeconomics as it deals with the practical economic activity of single persons and/or entities.

Is marketing a field of economics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, marketing falls under the [JEL code of **M**](https://www.aeaweb.org/econlit/jelCodes.php?view=jel#M), specifically **M31**.